# Can't get padding property from ContentPanel in Sencha GXT

Tags: css, gwt, gxt, uibinder

So I have `ContentPanel` instantiated via UiBinder. After I've created it with  `initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));` I'm trying to get it's body right padding. Have tried all of these methods :

```
panel.getBody().getAttribute("paddingRight");
panel.getBody().getPadding(com.sencha.gxt.core.client.Style.Side.RIGHT);
panel.getBody().getComputedStyle("paddingRight");
panel.getBody().getPropertyString("paddingRight");
panel.getBody().getPropertyInt("paddingRight");
panel.getBody().getStyle().getPadding();
panel.getBody().getStyle().getPaddingRight();
panel.getBody().getStyle().getProperty("paddingRight"));
```

But all of them returning just 0 or `null`. Tried to get `"padding-right"`, still no results. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved my problem - should call

```
panel.getBody().getPadding(com.sencha.gxt.core.client.Style.Side.RIGHT);
```

in `onLoad()` of parent `Composite`.